# How do I create two relations in one document

Tags: ruby, mongodb, associations, mongodb-query, mongomapper

I am using mongomapper and I am saving association using the following method:

```
class Task
  include MongoMapper::Document
  key :user_id, ObjectId #also works without this line

  belongs_to :user

def self.add(user)
  a = self.new
  a.user_id = user
  a.save
end
```

And in the User model I have added:  many :Tasks

Now, I would like to save two users (in the html form I select 2 users from the Users collection), without using the array, I want to save them separately:

```
class Task
  include MongoMapper::Document
  key :from_user_id, ObjectId # user1 links to the Users model
  key :to_user_id, ObjectId # user2 links to the Users model
```

How od I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoMapper has similar options as ActiveRecord when it comes to specifying keys and class names.  You'd do something like:

```
class Task
  include MongoMapper::Document
  key :to_user_id, ObjectId
  key :from_user_id, ObjectId
  belongs_to :from_user, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :from_user_id
  belongs_to :to_user, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :to_user_id
end
```

Comment: this created String instead of ObjectId. And when I call the result with result.to_user_id.name I get: undefined method `name' for "53c2be9456c02c3c90000001":String

Comment: Try specifying the `ObjectId` type when defining the key.  See edit.

Comment: Added, when calling: puts a.to_user_id.name I get undefined method `name' for BSON::ObjectId('53c2beda56c02c3cad000001'):BSON::ObjectId

Comment: Uh, yeah, because `to_user_id` is an `ObjectId`.  Do you mean `a.to_user.name`?

Comment: duh! stupid me :) Thank you! So now maybe second part of my issues:) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24724393/mongomapper-many-to-many-issue-with-array