# Mongomapper many to many issue with Array

Tags: ruby, associations, mongomapper

I would like to list all the task names for the User form the user's tasklist

But when I use the code below I get the following message:

```
undefined method `task_id' for ...
```

Here are my classes:

```
class User
  include MongoMapper::Document
  key :name, String
  key :tasklist, Array # I need this to hold ObjIds

  many :tasks, :in => :tasklist, :class_name => 'Task'

  def add(taskid)
    a = self.new
    a.task_id << taskid
    a.save
end

class Task
  include MongoMapper::Document
  key :name, String

  many :users
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
a = self.new
a.tasklist = [object1,object2]
a.save
```

Then I can iterate through all the object references using:

```
a = User.find(a.id)
a.tasks.each do |task|
  puts task.name
end
```

Comment: But now there is another issue, mongomapper seems to skip duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814688/mongomapper-association-skips-duplicates