# how iterate document with hash with associated values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongomapper

Example document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53c32ac056c02c506b000003"),
    "participants" : {
        "user" : ObjectId("53c32ac056c02c506b000002"), # id of the user from User model
        "active" : "pending"
    }
}
```

How do I show the user name using the ObjectId from the participants hash?

I have tried many, belongs_to but nothing works :(

Comment: user is in another mongodb collection, since mongodb doesn't support join, you have to do another query on that user collection.

Comment: beside basic ruby mongodb driver, http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/ruby/ also listed few high level mongodb drivers which provide similar automatic join (like rails ActiveRecord).

Comment: then why am I able to iterate through Array of associated objects and not hash?

Comment: I thought that if I am able to iterate through Array of objects:

Comment: depends on which ruby mongodb driver you are using, they all got different syntax. `belongs_to` is the syntax for `rails ActiveRecord`, it doesn't apply to mongodb.

Comment: Here is how I iterate through array of Objects, can I do the same for hashes? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24724393/mongomapper-many-to-many-issue-with-array

Comment: I am using mongomapper, but any other solution would be fine :) I just want to know if it is possible. Since I can create Array of associative objects and call them from one collection, I was wondering how to create hash with associative values and call them from the parent collection

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57243/discussion-between-huocp-and-meso-2600).